# How do you write a CSV in R with the matrix names (dimnames(M)) intact in R?

Tags: file-io, r, matrix

Is there a command in R that will allow you to write a CSV file that has the row and column names of a matrix (dimnames(M))? Whenever I output the file, the names are gone.

```
help(write)
```

doesn't mention that this is possible to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `write.csv`

Answer (score 1):

Use write.table(...,row.names=TRUE,col.names=TRUE,sep=",")

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is an [**entire manual**](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.pdf) dedicated to questions like this, it really does not hurt to look at those once in a while.

Comment: I agree.  I always find a new nugget or two when I skim through these.  A longer list of required reads can be found here: http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html